# THREE.StereoEffect effect changes the position of camera

Tags: javascript, three.js, parallax

I have been playing with THREE.js. I am having problems setting up a scene in a way I intend. 
  I guess due to the parallax, the camera in the stereoscopic side by side mode gets slightly translated to the side, and it is no longer at the origin (0,0,0). As a result - when looking at a cube positioned centrally in front of the camera the margins from the cube to the edge of the screen differ. As in the picture  - the inner margins are 8 pixels while the outer margins are 6 pixels.

[image]

Is there a way to eliminate it? My intention is to measure the actual field of view of the display so the margins should be identical for the sake of measurement validity.
  Also when I render the image without the stereo effect - the fov calculation gives completely different results (not a doubled fov as I would expect)